# How to get PHP syntax error to display a complete message with file name and line number?

Tags: php

I'm working on converting some old PHP code from version 5.6 to 7.3.  I had a syntax error and the message I got was:

```
[14-Nov-2020 11:33:16 America/Los_Angeles] syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
```

which gives no clue as to where the error was.  In this case I was able to switch back to 5.6 which give the complete information.  So how do I get PHP 7.3 to give the complete error message, like 5.6?  I tried Googling this problem, but could not find any mention of it, perhaps it's some kind of .ini setting?

Comment: Add these lines begin of you code (after <?php): ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); and see what happens.

Comment: I did that and it gives the exact same message, except to the screen instead of the error log.

Comment: Although it did also display an undefined variable error and that message did have the file and line.

Comment: Then you can see where error comes from!?! If you set ini_set('display_errors', 0); it doesn't show on the screen.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not where the error is displayed.  The problem is that the syntax error doesn't give the file name and line number.

Comment: That's weird! I think its a bug on your PHP version. Download another PHP version like 7.2, rename php7.3 folder to php7.3.bk and replace php7.2 and check again. I hop this should help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224564/discussion-between-george-and-farzan-takhsha).